# Nginx rewrite can't rewrite Cyrillic

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, cyrillic

I have had URLs on Cyrillic which I've changed to Latin about a month ago.
Now I am making redirects from error pages (webmaster tools), but for some reason Cyrillic URL rewriting is not working.

I did the following:

```
rewrite ^http://example.com/ru/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8B/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA-kovea-rocket-torch.html$ http://example.com/ru/gazovyy-rezak-kovea-rocket-torch/p570.html    permanent;
```

any ideas?

Comment: i got 404 every time

Comment: pritty interesting. some of url works fine, but others doesnt work